# The linear span of $Y$ and $z\in X\setminus Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

We are given a linear space $X$ over the reals. $Y$ is a linear subspace of $X$. We suppose that $Y$ is not all of $X$ and can therefore pick a $z$ which is in $X$ but not in $Y$. Now we define
$Z=\{y+az:y\in Y,a\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

In the book I'm reading, they call $Z$ the linear span of $Y$ and $z$. I have never come across this definition before. Does it, intuitively, mean that we are looking at every vector in $Y$ on which we add all possible lengths of the vector $z$?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can think of this is that if $B$ is a basis of $Y$ and $z\in X$, $$Z=\text{span}\big\{B\cup\{z\}\big\}.$$

Note that this still works if $z\in Y$, but in that case you get back $Y$.